# Error while building android-froyo source with custom application

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I am building android-froyo with application based on skia and putting that source inside packages/apps
while building its having error :-

***error: 'dynamic_cast' not permitted with -fno-rtti***

Kindly guide me how to solve this.